# Swift 4.2 - Decode JSON Where Same Key Is Different Type

Tags: ios, json, rest, swift4

I am decoding an object using the following model

```
struct ACDeviceLastData {
    var DA: ACDeviceLastDataBody = ACDeviceLastDataBody()
}

struct ACDeviceLastDataBody {
    var amOn: Bool = false
    var enabledZones: [Int] = []
    var fanSpeed: Int = 0
    var mode: Int = 0
    var tempTarget: Float = 0.00
}

extension ACDeviceLastData: Decodable {
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            //Create Container
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ACDeviceCodingKeys.self)

        //Decode Data
        DA = try container.decodeIfPresent(ACDeviceLastDataBody.self, forKey: .DA) ?? ACDeviceLastDataBody()
    }
}

extension ACDeviceLastDataBody: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        //Create Container
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ACDeviceCodingKeys.self)

        //Decode Data
        amOn = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .amOn) ?? false
        enabledZones = try container.decodeIfPresent([Int].self, forKey: .enabledZones) ?? []
        fanSpeed = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .fanSpeed) ?? 0
        mode = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .mode) ?? 0
        tempTarget = try container.decodeIfPresent(Float.self, forKey: .tempTarget) ?? 0.00
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the value of `DA` is not always the same type. It can sometimes be in the format of an array of integers and sometimes in the format of ACDevieLastDataBody. I've tried doing a do-try-catch but couldn't quite work out how to get that to work (if this is even the right thing to do)

My question here is, how would I go about decoding these without the decoder throwing when it is an array of integers. Any help is appreciated very much. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Catch the type mismatch error in the `init` method and decode the other type if it occurs. Or use an enum with associated types to distinguish the cases.

Comment: @vadian thanks for your suggestion. Any chance you could post an example for me as I'm not 100% certain how you'd implement that?

Comment: The question has been asked already [a couple of times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+decode+json+different+types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to choose a way how to store the data. For simplicity, let's store the array of `Int` as a separate property:

```
struct ACDeviceLastData {
   var DA: ACDeviceLastDataBody = ACDeviceLastDataBody()
   var DAasInts: [Int] = []
}

extension ACDeviceLastData: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ACDeviceCodingKeys.self)

        if let ints: [Int] = try? (container.decodeIfPresent([Int].self, forKey: .DA) ?? []) {
            // will pass here when `DA` is null or an array of ints
            DA = ACDeviceLastDataBody()
            DAasInts = ints
        } else {
            // null is already handled above
            DA = try container.decode(ACDeviceLastDataBody.self, forKey: .DA)
            DAasInts = []
        }
    }
}
```

You might want to represent your data differently, e.g. create `ACDeviceLastDataBody` from the array of ints.

Comment: Thank you, I eventually ended up using this approach and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to arrange the types in the `init(from decoder: Decoder)`

It's a simple conversion, mind the the types may not be exactly the same, so that compatibility is yours to arrange, your burden.

I can't see the JSON, but JSON to Code, is very easy to do, as JSON types are always simple, at atomic level.

I hope it helped...

You have a nice day!